# OrientDB select record count from all graph classes

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

Any way to get record count for each graph class (V, E and their subclasses)?

I tried to build query in SQL format for current case:

```
SELECT @class, count(*) FROM V GROUP BY @class
SELECT @class, count(*) FROM E GROUP BY @class
```

But using `count()` + `GROUP BY` is extrimply slow combination.

While console command `list classes` works fast and return values for count of records in each class (field `RECORDS`), how to extract this counts via SQL query (or via OrientJS API)?

Comment: Hi, could you post an example of your schema? and which version are you using?

Comment: Hi I tride your case and, your query works, if the problem is the slowness you can use an index

Comment: The main problem is speed of getting count value while used `case()` + `group by`. While used `list classes` (I need to get count information from classes with billion records, in in schema stored ~700 classes), it works much faster.

Comment: Have you tried with an index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is find a way to:

1. Get list of all classes if database
2. Get count of records that stored in each class

**Technical details**

In OrientDB functions you have access to `orient` variable that have `.getDatabase()` method. And this method return JAVA [ODatabaseDocumentTx](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/document/ODatabaseDocumentTx.html) class instance. This class provides the method `.countClass(className)` that returns the number of the records of the class `className` ([method documentation](http://orientdb.com/javadoc/latest/com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/document/ODatabaseDocumentTx.html#countClass-java.lang.String-)) and it works realy fast.

**Solution**

Create function in OrientDB Studio with name "getClassCounts", language "javascript", idempotent: true:

```
var db = orient.getDatabase();
var classesRawInfo = db.getMetadata().getImmutableSchemaSnapshot().getClasses().toArray();
var classesList = {};
var i = classesRawInfo.length;

while(--i) {
    var className = classesRawInfo[i].name;
    classesList[className] = db.countClass(className);
}

return classesList;
```

Executing:

- via SQL: `SELECT getClassCounts()`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible, also because it wouldn't so fast as in the console

Comment: Sorry for missinformation. I use OrientDB v.2.1.15 and try to get this count values via OrientJS v.2.2.0 (on node.js server). And it is not support `list classes` command, if it used as query. I tried to find where stored count values for classes (or alternative faster way to get it instead of `count(*)` function).